# Delete negative elements which are between positives only

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = [1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9,
     2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]
```

I want to do like:

```
a = [1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2,
     -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]
```

which deletes only 4th and 8th elements, which are single negative elements between two positive elements.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9,
     2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] < 0 and a[i - 1] > 0  and a[i + 1] > 0:
        np.delete(a[i])
print(a)
```

This did not work. Can I know where I have to fix?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Numpy? Why do you expect Numpy to be useful or relevant for solving the problem? As far as I can tell, `a` is an ordinary Python list.

Comment: Do you want the input to be a list or a numpy array? Do you want the output to be a list or a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

Because you ask about numpy in the subject line and also attempt to use np.delete() in your code, I assume you intend for `a` to be a numpy array.

Here is a way to do what your question asks using vectorized operations in numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,6,-2,4,5,8,-3,9,2,-5,-7,-9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2])
b = np.concatenate([a[1:], [np.NaN]])
c = np.concatenate([[np.NaN], a[:-1]])
d = (a<0)&(b>0)&(c>0)
print(a[~d])
```

Output:

```
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
```

What we've done is to shift `a` one to the left with NaN fill on the right (`b`) and one to the right with NaN fill on the left (`c`), then to create a boolean mask `d` using vectorized compare and boolean operators `<`, `>` and `&` which is True only where we want to delete single negative values sandwiched between positives. Finally, we use the `~` operator to flip the boolean value of the mask and use it to filter out the unneeded negative values in `a`.

**UPDATE**: Based on benchmarking of several possible strategies for answering your question (see below), the conclusion is that the following solution appears to be the most performative in answering OP's question (credit to @Kelly Bundy for suggesting this in a comment):

```py
a = np.concatenate((a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]))
```

**UPDATE**: Here are some `timeit()` comparisons of several variations on answers given for this question using NumPy 1.22.2.

The fastest of the 8 strategies is:
`a = np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]])`

A close second is:
`a = a[np.concatenate([[True], ~((a[1:-1]<0)&(a[2:]>0)&(a[:-2]>0)), [True]])]`

The strategies using `np.r_()`, either with `np.delete()` or with a boolean mask and `[]` syntax, are about twice as slow as the fastest.

The strategy using `numpy.roll()` is about 3 times as slow as the fastest. **Note**: As highlighted by in a comment by @Kelly Bundy, the `roll()` strategy in the benchmark does not give a correct answer to this question in  all cases (though for the particular input example it happens to). I have nevertheless included it in the benchmark because the performance of `roll()` relative to `concatenate()` and `r_()` may be of general interest beyond the narrow context of this question.

Results:

```
foo_1 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_2 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_3 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_4 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_5 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_6 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_7 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
foo_8 output:
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
Timeit results:
foo_1 ran in 1.2354546000715346e-05 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_2 ran in 1.0962473000399769e-05 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_3 ran in 7.733614000026136e-06 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_4 ran in 7.751871000509709e-06 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_5 ran in 5.856722998432815e-06 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_6 ran in 7.5727709988132115e-06 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_7 ran in 1.7790602000895887e-05 seconds using 100000 iterations
foo_8 ran in 5.435103999916464e-06 seconds using 100000 iterations
```

Code that generated the results:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,6,-2,4,5,8,-3,9,2,-5,-7,-9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2])
from timeit import timeit
def foo_1(a):
    a = a if a.shape[0] < 2 else np.delete(a, np.r_[False, (a[1:-1] < 0) & (a[:-2] > 0) & (a[2:] > 0), False])
    return a
def foo_2(a):
    a = a if a.shape[0] < 2 else a[np.r_[True, ~((a[1:-1] < 0) & (a[:-2] > 0) & (a[2:] > 0)), True]]
    return a
def foo_3(a):
    b = np.concatenate([a[1:], [np.NaN]])
    c = np.concatenate([[np.NaN], a[:-1]])
    d = (a<0)&(b>0)&(c>0)
    a = a[~d]
    return a
def foo_4(a):
    a = a[~((a<0)&(np.concatenate([a[1:], [np.NaN]])>0)&(np.concatenate([[np.NaN], a[:-1]])>0))]
    return a
def foo_5(a):
    a = a if a.shape[0] < 2 else a[np.concatenate([[True], ~((a[1:-1]<0)&(a[2:]>0)&(a[:-2]>0)), [True]])]
    return a
def foo_6(a):
    a = a if a.shape[0] < 2 else np.delete(a, np.concatenate([[False], (a[1:-1]<0)&(a[2:]>0)&(a[:-2]>0), [False]]))
    return a
def foo_7(a):
    mask_bad = (
       (a < 0) &  # the value is < 0 AND
       (np.roll(a,1) >= 0) & # the value to the right is >= 0
       (np.roll(a,-1) >= 0) # the value to the left is >= 0
    )
    mask_good = ~mask_bad
    a = a[mask_good]
    return a
def foo_8(a):
    a = np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]])
    return a

foo_count = 8
for foo in ['foo_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(foo_count)]:
    print(f'{foo} output:')
    print(eval(f"{foo}(a)"))

n = 100000
print(f'Timeit results:')
for foo in ['foo_' + str(i + 1) for i in range(foo_count)]:
    t = timeit(f"{foo}(a)", setup=f"from __main__ import a, {foo}", number=n) / n
    print(f'{foo} ran in {t} seconds using {n} iterations')
```

Comment: Given that the roll one isn't correct, I wouldn't call it a "solution". I probably wouldn't even include it in the benchmark.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Strictly within the context of this question, I take your point on `roll()`, but the broader question of how `roll()` stacks up against `concatenate()` and `r_()` is one that I find interesting. I'll update my answer to highlight your point about the `roll()` strategy not delivering a correct answer for the question.

Comment: Hmm, when I run your code, foo_1 and foo_6 are also wrong, they delete the first two numbers (I think because True/False are interpreted as 1/0). Did that change in a newer NumPy version?

Comment: Not sure. I'm running NumPy 1.22.2 and the outputs (which are shown in my answer) are identical across the first 6 strategies (as well as the 7th using `roll()`, but that's probably just luck).

Comment: Btw some solution(s?) crash if the input has fewer than two elements.

Comment: Foo2 adds one more logical operation than my answer. Also, what about just replacing `np.r_[True, ... True]` with `np.concatenate(([True], ..., [True]))`?

Comment: Another contender: `np.concatenate((a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]))`.

Comment: @Mad Physicist Isn't that what `foo_5()` does? That's actually the fastest strategy of the bunch.

Comment: Also, your tests are dominated by overhead. Testing numpy on short arrays is fairly pointless, since the time will be few microseconds, most of which are spent performing the transition from python to C and back. A much better test would be to randomly generate a sufficiently large array (100k+ elements) and time that.

Comment: @constantstranger. Good call. I glossed over it somehow :) Although again, I object to the introduction of an unnecessary logistical operation

Comment: @MadPhysicist Whether testing much larger arrays is better depends on what the user actually has. I once had a linear time answer lose against a quadratic one because the OP actually had lists of less than ten elements.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Assuming you meant `np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]])`, that's slightly faster than the previous record holder. I'll update my answer to include it.

Comment: I meant it as written, why wouldn't I?

Comment: I added one more suggestion: wrap the mask in `np.flatnonzero` or `np.where(...)[0]`

Comment: @Kelly Bundy When I first tried your "contender", it gave an error and I adjusted it slightly, but now it works fine, so perhaps it was a copy/paste issue by me. By the way, thanks for the heads up on the crashes for len < 2, that's now fixed

Comment: @KellyBundy. That sounds like premature optimization. What were you doing to 10 elements that made it a bottleneck.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't remember what they were doing. But in general, it's not just large lists/arrays that can be slow, it can also be small ones if you have many. And there's no indication in the question here about this.

Comment: Darn, I realized mine isn't quite right, either, gives a wrong result when there is exactly one element. Can be fixed your way or for example with `a[1:][-1:]` as the tail.

Comment: @Brian Jan Has this helped with your question? Do you need any additional help?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that handles edges correctly and doesn't create an unholy number of temporary arrays:

```
a = np.delete(a, np.r_[False, (a[1:-1] < 0) & (a[:-2] > 0) & (a[2:] > 0), False])
```

Alternatively, you can create the positive rather than the negative mask

```
a = a[np.r_[True, (a[1:-1] >= 0) | (a[:-2] <= 0) | (a[2:] <= 0), True]]
```

Since `np.concatenate` is faster than `np.r_`, you could rephrase the masks as

```
np.concatenate(([False], (a[1:-1] < 0) & (a[:-2] > 0) & (a[2:] > 0), [False])
```

and

```
np.concatenate(([True], (a[1:-1] >= 0) | (a[:-2] <= 0) | (a[2:] <= 0), [True]))
```

In some cases, you might get extra mileage out of applying `np.where(...)[0]` or `np.flatnonzero` to the mask. This works sometimes because it avoids having to recompute the size of the number of masked elements twice.

Comment: Meh... nine vs ten temporary arrays, if I counted correctly. Doesn't seem like a big difference.

Comment: I like the brevity of your one-line solution. That said, according to `timeit()`, your solution takes about 2x longer to run that the `concatenate()` based solution in my answer, whatever the relative number of temporary arrays.

Comment: @constantstranger. It's usually time or memory. You chose to sacrifice memory. I have PTSD from doing embedded work.

Comment: @constantstranger. Check out the new solution. I suspect that the time difference depends mostly on the ratio of elements to remove vs ones to keep

Comment: Please see my updated answer showing the `timeit()` results, which don't seem to be that sensitive to keep vs remove. Instead, the main takeaway seems to be that `r_()` lags `concatenate()` and `roll()` lags `r_()`.

Comment: Please note @Kelly Bundy's comment to my answer regarding crashes for fewer than 2 elements, you may want to make sure your answer is OK in this regard as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional logic

```
if a[i] < 0 and a[i - 1] > 0 and a[i + 1] > 0
```

seems sound and readable to me. But it would have issues with the boundary cases:

```
[1, 2, -3] -> IndexError: list index out of range
[-1, 2, 3] -> [2, 3]
```

Handling it properly could be as simple as skipping the first and last element of you list with

```
for i in range(1, len(a) - 1)
```

### Test

```
import numpy as np


def del_neg_between_pos(a):
    delete_idx = []
    for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
        if a[i] < 0 and a[i - 1] > 0 and a[i + 1] > 0:
            delete_idx.append(i)

    return np.delete(a, delete_idx)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a1 = [1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9, 2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]
    a2 = [1, 2, -3]
    a3 = [-1, 2, 3]
    for a in [a1, a2, a3]:
        print(del_neg_between_pos(a))
```

### Output

```
[ 1  3  6  4  5  8  9  2 -5 -7 -9  3  6 -7 -6  2]
[ 1  2 -3]
[-1  2  3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner is

```
a[1:-1] = [a[i] for i in range(1, len(a) - 1) if not (a[i] < 0 and a[i-1] > 0 and a[i+1] > 0)]
```

The above assigns elements from the list `a` that are not negative and preceded and followed by a positive number to a slicing of `a`.

**Output** (from printing `a`)

```
[1, 3, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]
```

**Timings**

---

The below timings compare my approach above to the fastest approach in @constantstranger's answer:

```
a = np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)], a[-1:]])
```

My suggested approach is obviously optimized for the case where you want both the input and output to be a list. However, even in suboptimal (for my approach) input/output configurations, for this input, my approach appears to be faster than the `numpy` approach.

**Input/Output Configuration 1**

- Input is a `list` (as in your question).
- Output is a `numpy` array.

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: a = [1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9, 2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2]
   ...: a[1:-1] = [a[i] for i in range(1, len(a) - 1) if not (a[i] < 0 and a[i-
   ...: 1] > 0 and a[i+1] > 0)]
   ...: a = np.array(a)
   ...: 
   ...: 
3.08 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: a = np.array([1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9, 2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6,
   ...:  2])
   ...: a = np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)]
   ...: , a[-1:]])
   ...: 
   ...: 
6.66 µs ± 16.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

**Input/Output Configuration 2**

- Input and output is a numpy array (as assumed in other answers).

The input

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 6, -2, 4, 5, 8, -3, 9, 2, -5, -7, -9, 3, 6, -7, -6, 2])
```

Timings:

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: b = a.tolist()
   ...: b[1:-1] = [b[i] for i in range(1, len(b) - 1) if not (b[i] < 0 and b[i-
   ...: 1] > 0 and b[i+1] > 0)]
   ...: b = np.array(b)
   ...: 
   ...: 
3.1 µs ± 10.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: b = np.concatenate([a[:1], a[1:-1][(a[1:-1]>=0)|(a[2:]<=0)|(a[:-2]<=0)]
   ...: , a[-1:]])
   ...: 
   ...: 
4.8 µs ± 13.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

**Remarks**

---

The above holds for this specific input. A larger input size may have different results (particularly due to the conversion between types). I would be happy to provide timings that vary the input size (presented graphically). However, it would be useful to know whether you want the input or output to be a `list` or a `numpy` array.